# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' to type 'Project.Form1'

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, user-controls, casting

I have a `UserControl` that uses some of the public properties that I have available on my Form, at the top of the `Paint` event for this `UserControl`, I reference the `Parent` of the control and cast it to the type of my Form.

```
var _parent = (Form1)Parent;
```

This code works however, in the Design view, an error is thrown and all I see in place of the `UserControl` is a white box displaying the error in the title of this post. The stacktrace leads directly to this line of code.

Right now, I have fixed this error by re-routing this cast through a Property in my UserControl

```
    public Form1 ControlParent
    {
        get
        {
            if (Parent != null)
            {
                return (Form1)Parent;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is kind of a little much for something that just breaks the Design view.. any other ideas?

Comment: If you do not care about the display of your control at design time, and only wish for the error to disappear you can use the "DesignMode" property in the Paint event of your user control .. if (!DesignMode) {... paint code ...}

Comment: @Preets Wow, that is also very useful. You should have posted this as an answer but thanks for you input =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code it looks like your child `Control` instance can already deal with `ControlParent` being `null`.  Hence the simplest fix would be to just do the following

```
public Form1 ControlParent
{
    get
    {
        return Parent as Form1;
    }
}
```

Note: In general it's a bad idea to depend on the `Parent` of a `Control` being of a specific type.  It prevents it from being re-hosted in other controls and can break designers which often fudge types around in order to provide a nice design experience.  If you must depend on a value like `Parent` being of a specific type make sure to have a fall back plan which doesn't crash in the face of a different type.

Comment: The above code would still break the designer. This isn't a run-time issue. For some reason, the Design view of my Form1 cannot display the UserControl because of that line of code. Like I said above, the code works wonderfully but the Design view suffers.

Comment: @Kyle, if so then it sounds like your child control can't handle if `ControlParent` returns a `null` value.  It must be able to do so

Comment: @JaredPar The control CAN handle a null value for Parent. The cast is the issue. When the Design View tries to display the Control, it has to call the onPaint event, which causes that cast to break. I have no idea why, and that is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: @JaredPar Does "Parent as Form1" do something different than "(Form1)Parent?" If so, what?

Comment: @Kyle, it's very different.  The `(Form1)Parent` version does an dynamic runtime cast.  If the type of `Parent` is not `Form1` then an exception will be thrown.  In the `Parent as Form1` version, if the type of `Parent` is not compatible with `Form1` then it will just return `null`

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that parent is not null in first code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting form's owner and then accessing that property the way you are trying through the parent property.