# How to Correctly Reference Parent Form from UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, designer

All, I have a `UserCostrol` which I have recently had to change. This changed required me to reference the `Parent` form and to use a property from this form. These references have seemingly broken the designer - I was getting an error

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' to type 'Project.SettingsForm'"

which was discribed in [Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' to type 'Project.Form1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780220/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-windows-forms-form-to-type-project-form1).

I have added a property to handle the reference to the `Parent` form as described in the answer refernced above, but now the designer error is saying

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' to type 'Project.SettingsForm'".

The first line which the compilier is moaning about is marked with `'<-- Here'` in the code below

```
public partial class UiSettingFascia : UserControl, ISettingsControl
{
    public UiSettingFascia()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UiSettingFascia_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadSettings();
        CheckBoxShowTabs.CheckedChanged += Workbook_StateChanged;
        CheckBoxShowVirticalScroll.CheckedChanged += Workbook_StateChanged;
        CheckBoxShowHorizontolScroll.CheckedChanged += Workbook_StateChanged;
    }

    public void LoadSettings()
    {
        UserSettings userSettings = UserSettings.Instance();
        ...
        MainRibbonForm mainRibbonForm = (ControlParent).MainRibbonForm; // <-- Here.
        ...
    }
}
```

To attempt to fix the initial problem [**"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' to type 'Project.SettingsForm'"**] I have created the following property

```
public SettingsForm ControlParent
{
    get { return Parent as SettingsForm; }
}
```

How can I get around this problem [**"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' to type 'Project.SettingsForm'"**] whilst maintaining my functionality of the `UserControl`?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use an event to talk to the parent form.

Comment: Why don't you just use: `var settingsForm = (SettingsForm)this.ParentForm;`?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici that's the point, during design-time compilation of the `UserControl`'s initialisation the control should not know anything about the parent forms type. I have attempted to 'abstract it away' using a property which still isn't ideal, clearly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [this extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427420/674700):

```
public static class DesignTimeHelper
{
    public static bool IsInDesignMode
    {
        get
        {
            bool isInDesignMode = (
                LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime || 
                Debugger.IsAttached == true);
            if (!isInDesignMode)
            {
                using (var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
                {
                    return process
                        .ProcessName.ToLowerInvariant()
                        .Contains("devenv");
                }
            }
            return isInDesignMode;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your `LoadSettings` method:

```
public void LoadSettings()
{
    if (!DesignTimeHelper.IsInDesignMode)
    {
        var settingsForm = (SettingsForm)this.ParentForm;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for your help. This looked very promising, but I am still getting the 'Unable to cast...' when attempting to add the `UserControl` to my form. See my edit for more information...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to code in some design-time behavior. During design-time, the parent of the UserControl may in fact be Visual Studio (or some component thereof). That's how Visual Studio is able to give you a GUI for working with the control during design-time—it actually hosts the control; it's actually executing.

You probably need to set a an attribute on the property that takes the parent form to give it some other behavior during design-time. Also, I think there's a property on UserControls called `DesignMode` that will be true when the control is in design mode—this way, you can give the control different behavior at design-time vs. run-time. There are plenty of articles on MSDN about creating controls and configuring their design-time vs. run-time behavior.